# In Github, how to search repositories with multiple keywords?

Tags: github

[image: Github search example]

I want to search these repositories which's title contain 'keyword-1' **or** 'keyword-2' **or** 'keyword-3'.

I have read the Github search help documents and search api documents, But I still have no idea how to search with multiple keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is the way you are demonstrating. I mean just use the tags separated by simple space. I have just tested that the first repositories that are shown are those containing all the tags that I am searching. Give it a try, it must be working just fine

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, if I want to search 'framework', 'blockchain', 'Mock', so I tried like this [link](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=framework+blockchain+Mock&type=), but not work.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a repository that is marked with **all** these tags?

Comment: Not **all**. I mean the relationship of these keywords is **or** not **and**.

Comment: I am afraid this is not yet possible. I found [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/660) but I think it is not yet implemented!

Comment: Thank you! The issue's suggestion is great, that just what I mean. Hope Github will implement it.

Comment: @codesve Do u happen to know how to search the intersection of keywords? i.e. Keyword_1 **and** Keyword_2 **and** Keyword_3

Answer (score 2):

In 2024, you can now use *booleans*:

**OR:**

`"FOO" OR "BAR" OR "BAZ" language:TypeScript`

[image: OR]

**AND:**

`"FOO" AND "BAR" AND "BAZ" language:TypeScript`

[image: AND]

Answer (score 0):

for now you can use `curl` and `jq` to achieve this. Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/usametov/af8f13a351a66fb05a9895f11417dd9d) gist